# php display elements in a checkerboard pattern

Tags: php, html, css

I display elements from the php side like this:

```
<?php foreach ($cases as $case) { ?>
    <div class="case">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="<?= $case->getImageUrl() ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="text"><?= $case->text ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

And on the html page they look like this

```css
.case {
  padding: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="case">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JMHHMVl.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="text">case 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="case">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/m3cq9ez.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="text">case 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="case">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IKXSAiw.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="text">case 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make it so that `col-6` are alternately swapped and the elements on the page are displayed in a checkerboard pattern, like this

```css
.case {
  padding: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-t4GWSVZO1eC8BM339Xd7Uphw5s17a86tIZIj8qRxhnKub6WoyhnrxeCIMeAqBPgdZGlCcG2PrZjMc+Wr78+5Xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="case">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JMHHMVl.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="text">case 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="case">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="text">case 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/m3cq9ez.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="case">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/IKXSAiw.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="text">case 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bootstrap switched to `display: flex` its possible with pure modern CSS like this:

```
.case:nth-of-type(2n) .row{
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

No changes to HTML required.